# Characterization of finite field in residue ring

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $f\in \mathbb F_q[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Let $e$ be a positive integer. Let $R= \mathbb F_q[x]/(f^e)$. 
Let $y\in R$.

Prove that if $y^{q-1}-1=0$ then $y\in \mathbb F_q^*$.

Notice that for $e=1$ $R$ is a finite field, so the statement is immediate by the characterization of the subfield $\mathbb F_q$.

Edit: please find the answer below.

Comment: What have you tried? This sure looks like homework, and this is not a homework-solving site.

Comment: And this is not a homework question, it is a curiosity.

Comment: As you say it is a curiosity, please add context in (say) the way this problem is interesting to you and what approaches you've tried to solve it.  For example, what can we say in the case $e=1$?

Comment: I just replied to my own question. For e=1 the situation is trivial because R is a finite field.

Comment: @Reyx_0: Your answer provides context, but I would incorporate the comment regarding $e=1$ into the question rather then leaving it in a comment, where it can get lost.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so this is the answer (short version):

by reducing modulo $f$ observe that if $y^{q-1}-1=0$, by standard properties of finite fields, this implies that $y=c+fg$ for some $f,g\in R$.

Now multiply the equation above by $y$ getting $y^q-y$, and plug in the special form for $y$, getting $(fg)^q-fg=fg((fg)^{q-1}-1)=0$ but now $(fg)^{q-1}-1$ is invertible in $R$, so $fg$ must be already zero, which leads to $y=c$.